# How do you say 'Is it no longer for free?' or 'it's not free?' [to watch]

Tags: grammaire, apprentissage

Meaning I have to pay for it now as opposed to before where I can get it without payment.

Comment: For a web service (with some kind of registration) "Souscription <del>au contenu</del> désormais payante" . For a publicly available video "Visionnage désormais payant".

Comment: @gilaro Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to say it are :

> *Ce n'est plus gratuit.*
> *On ne peut plus le voir sans payer.*
> *Maintenant, c'est payant.*
> *C'est désormais payant* (Thanks to@Gilaro's comment.)